# Android Freemarker Class merging

Tags: android, merge, kotlin, freemarker

I'm trying to make a template and cannot find a solution for this case:

I have a class - Repository, something like:

```
interface UserRepository {
    fun registryUser(user: UserEntity): Observable<UserEntity>
}
```

With my template I want to add a method to this interface, e.g. updateUser(). It means that I want to achieve:

```
interface UserRepository {
    fun registryUser(user: UserEntity): Observable<UserEntity>
    fun updateUser(user: UserEntity): Observable<UserEntity>
}
```

In template.xml I've created a new parameter:

```
<parameter
    id="methodName"
    name="Method Name"
    type="string"
    constraints="nonempty|unique"
    default="updateUser"
    help="creates method in Repository" />
```

... and this code is for BlankRepository:

```
    interface UserRepository {
        fun ${methodName}()
    }
```

**Question:** How can I merge my current UserRepository.kt with the code of template?

Trying to do this in recipe.xml.ftl at this line:

```
    <merge from="root/src/app_package/Repository.kt.ftl"
         to="app/src/main/java/${slashedPackageName(packageName)}/domain/modules/${moduleName}/${entityName}Repository.kt" />
```

but it doesn't work! Stacktrace:

```
    Only XML or Gradle files can be merged at this point: C:\Users\,,\domain\modules\moduleName\Repository.kt
java.lang.RuntimeException: Only XML or Gradle files can be merged at this point: C:\Users\..\domain\modules\moduleName\Repository.kt
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.recipe.DefaultRecipeExecutor.merge(DefaultRecipeExecutor.java:303)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.recipe.Recipe$MergeInstruction.execute(Recipe.java:215)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.recipe.Recipe.executeInstructions(Recipe.java:120)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.recipe.Recipe.execute(Recipe.java:105)
```

Is there another way?

Comment: Update: It seems like exception come from https://github.com/JetBrains/android/blob/master/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/templates/RecipeMergeUtils.java